# Write a program to solve the topological sorting problem by using Depth First Search (DFS) algorithm

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search, topological-sort

I want to use topological sorting using Depth First Search (DFS) for the given problem (the directed graph attached below).

[click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JV6TH.png).

Could you please help by writing the appropriate code for the given problem using any programming language?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

To recap: an ordering of the vertices of a graph is a topological sorting if all edges in the graph lead from higher-numbered vertices to lower-numbered vertices (or the other way around).

This means, that if, having a vertex `V`, you'd be able to somehow visit all vertices accessible from `V` and give them numbers lower than the number you give to `V`, then all edges going out of `V` will lead to vertices numbered lower than `V`, so they will conform to the definition of a topological sorting.

It is now our goal to achieve the above for all vertices.

Recall that a DFS could be useful here, because a DFS visits all vertices accessible from a given vertex.

We must run the DFS for all vertices, but since the DFS is a recursive algorithm, it will run itself for all vertices accessible from other vertices for which the DFS is run. Thus, we must run the DFS for all vertices, numbering the vertices in the order in which we ***exit*** from the DFS function, because at the end of the DFS function we know that all vertices accessible from a given vertex have been visited.

Here's some sample code in C++:

```cpp
#include <vector> // we'll need vector for an adjacency list graph representation

const maxN = 1'000'000 // maximum number of vertices

vector<int> graph[maxN]; // the adjacency list representation of the graph

bool visited[maxN]; // filled with the value false by default
int postOrder[maxN]; // array with the so-called post-order ordering of the vertices
int counter = 1;

void DFS(int v) {
  visited[v] = true; // mark vertex as visited
  for (int neighbour : graph[v]) { // for each neighbour of v
    if (!visited[neighbour]) { // if the neighbour wasn't already visited
      DFS(neighbour); // run the DFS for that neighbour
    }
  }
  // Finally, after all the vertices accessible from v have been numbered,
  // give v the next number, and increase the counter.
  postOrder[v] = counter;
  counter++;
}

void sortTopologically() {
  // For each unvisited vertex, run the DFS starting in that vertex.
  for (int v = 0; v < maxN; v++) {
    if (!visited[v]) {
      DFS(v);
    }
  }
}
```

This is called a [post-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Post-order,_LRN) ordering and is a very common way to topologically sort a directed graph. You can then easily check if the topological sorting exists by verifying that all edges lead from a higher-numbered vertex to a lower-numbered vertex.

Good luck with your university course!